# 0xc000007b error in running a c++ made program

Tags: c++, windows, mfc

The title of this question may be repetitious, but I didn't find a suitable solution.
I made a c++ mfc project with VS2015(x64_release_mode) and a lot of third party libraries. 
My program works fine on my computer (windows 10, x64), but when I run it on another computers, the below error comes up:

"the application was unable to start correctly 0xc000007b."

I gathered all dependant third party dlls and also I installed MSVS_redistributable_2015_x64.

I used dependancy_walker on it and I've got some nonsense errors. I say nonsense because I've got those errors 
even in my own computer(which my program works in it) and the errors point to some MS dlls that are installed correctly (As I think).
I even installed whole visual studio 2015 but the result was the same. Is there anything  I've missed?

P.S. I didn't mix any 32-bit thing with my program. All my works are in the 64-bit world.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks Alex. I haven't use Event viewer before. What should I do with it and how is it supposed to help?

Comment: Did you open the 64bit version of the Dependency Walker? ..I doubt that the information it shows is nonsense. [Here](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/43092-63-application-unable-start-correctly-0xc000007b) some people had the same issue.

Comment: The error code 0xC000007B is [STATUS_INVALID_IMAGE_FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc704588.aspx). It's usually caused by trying to load a module with mismatching bitness (loading a 32-bit image into a 64-bit process or vice versa). You can enable [loader snaps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/show-loader-snaps) to diagnose the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thank all you guys for your comments. I found the real problem so I post it here to share with other programmers.

I used opencv_world340.dll and it was built along with cuda and nvidia libraries, so it needs some dll named "nvcuda.dll". I picked it up from my computer earlier so there was no "missing nvcuda.dll" error, but that dll isn't supposed to work with every computer and gives the 0x000007b error.

the other computer I used for testing my exe, has no graphic card, so there was no nvidia installation and no compatible nvcuda.dll.

I finally built opencv dlls without involving nvidia libraries and the problem has been solved for the GPU-less computer !